# Optimize Hibernate entities saving?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

Is there a way to reduce unnecessary/empty fields in SQL inserts and SQL updates?

For example, I have a single hibernate entity class mapped to a table that has 10 columns. The populating of data is actually done in two phases. When the user submit a request, I will insert the request information into the table with the hibernate entity, but populating only 7 fields. After some processing (wait for other users interaction for example), I will populate the remaining 3 fields (with the id given from the previous insert).

If I stick with a single entity class, for the second update, the steps I do is as follows:

1) Load the entity identified by id

2) Save the entity, which generates sql that seems to be sending all the fields over.

Alternatively, I created two entity class, and point to the same table and save them seperately.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Kent

Edit:

What I really like to achieve is something to the following effect:
insert t(id,field1,field2) (?,?,?)
update t set field3=? field4=? where id=?

The best I could achieve now with dynamicUpdate=true is
insert t(id,field1,field2) (?,?,?)
select field1,field2,field3,field4 from t where id=?
update t set field3=? field4=? where id=?

Is there a way to eliminate that select statement? The original persisted object is not stored anywhere in memory after the insert.

An additional note. The entity class is annotated with Hibernate validation. I am currently trying out to achieve the above desired effect, so I commented them out. But when I turn them back on, I get validation errors due to @NotNull and @NotEmpty.

Comment: dynamicUpdate = true works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the annotation:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
```

to the top of your entity only the fields that have changed will be sent to the database.

Comment: I tried it out, and it works. But is there a way to eliminate the step where I have to load the entity first? I would like to eliminate the extra 'select' statement to the database(assuming the entity is not cached in the session)

Comment: I'm sure there are some hacks out their to achieve this.
(e.g. keep the original object somewhere and then do a merge or use bulk update)
However, if an extra select statement worries you perhaps hibernate isnt the right choice.  For me its a question of performance vs maintainability.